# If a subgroup of $S_{n}$ contains an $n$-cycle and an $(n - 1)$-cycle then it is doubly transitive?

Tags: group-theory

How to show that If a subgroup of $S_{n}$ contains an $n$-cycle and an $(n - 1)$-cycle then it is doubly transitive ?

I have to show that action is transitive on set all distinct pairs $(i,j)$ where $1\leq i,j\leq n$.

How should I proceed ?

Comment: If you do not know this already, try to prove that a group is doubly transitive if and only if it is transitive, and a point-stabiliser is transitive on the rest of the points.

Then, try to apply this to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality one can consider the second cycle to move the points $\{1,\ldots,n-1\}$. Let $c_1$ and $c_2$ be the two cycles under consideration and $G = \langle c_1, c_2 \rangle$. Consider the subset of $G \supseteq V = \{c_2^jc_1^i \mid 0 \leq i < n,\ 0 \leq j < n-1\}$ and the action of $V$ on the $n(n-1)$ tuples $[x,y], x\neq y \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ being the restriction of the action of $G$ on these tuples : $[x,y]^g = [x^g,y^g]$. The set of tuples $[1,n]^v,\ v \in V$ has $n(n-1)$ elements by the pigeonhole principle. Indeed, we have, after a small calculation, that $[1,n]^v = [1,n]^w \iff v = w$. The conlusion is that $G$ is 2-transitive.